# django: building a formset from a given custom form and a queryset

Tags: django, django-forms

Again a fairly generic task with forms that seems to be tricky. I'm trying to put together a bunch of custom forms, all different instances of the same form class constructed with different args, one for each entry in a given model.

For example, this custom form lets the user tick a checkbox if they've been to a destination, and select (multiple) activites they've done whilst there:

```
class VisitorDestinationForm(Form):
    def __init__(self, visitor, destination, *args, **kwargs):
        super(VisitorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        visitorDestinations = visitor.destinations.all()
        self.fields[destination.destination] = forms.BooleanField()
        self.fields[destination.destination].initial = destination in visitorDestinations
```

And I would like to make a formset with one of these forms for each destination in my `Destination` queryset. (I can handle the `visitor` arg using curry, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622982/django-passing-custom-form-parameters-to-formset))

The accepted answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989129/building-a-formset-dynamically) implies that `modelformset_factory` can take a simply a (custom) form and a (unrelated) queryset.

But if I try that I get an error:I can't use `modelformset_factory`, because the `VisitorDestinationForm` are not modelforms for the model I get my queryset (they are related though, and they should take a model instance in the constructor). This is confirmed if I look into the code (django 1.3)

It looks like django only handles 3 cases:

- formset_factory: a set of forms of the same type constructed with the
  same params
- modelformset_factory: a set of model forms for a queryset
  from that model
- inlineformset_factory: a set of forms for related queryset linked via FK (**NOT** M2M)

But there seems to be nothing if you want to put together a list of custom forms that are initialised from a list of objects. I'm surprised about this, I thought it would be quite a common situation

Will I have to write my own custom formset_factory, by overriding the `_construct_forms` method in `BaseFormSet`? Or should I simply handle the bunch of forms separately in my view, and is there something to watch out for in this case (I heard validation can be tricky)?